# phpMyAdmin: "URI too large"

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm using [XAMPP 5.6.15 for Windows](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html). I set up many tables with lots of attributes and some content.
When I click on "Designer" in `phpMyAdmin`, then on "export schema", I get this error:

> Submitted URI too large!
>
> The length of the requested URL exceeds the capacity limit for this
>   server. The request cannot be processed.

The URI looks as follows:

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/schema_export.php?t_x[myTable1.amp_vs_msaccess]=51&t_y[myTable2.amp_vs_msaccess]=152&t_v[myTable3.amp_vs_msaccess]...[myTable500.amp_vs_msaccess]
```

I already tried different options like PDF, SVG etc.

I want to get a visual representation of my tables and their relationships.

Is there any other way to export my schema?
Can I switch to `POST` instead of `GET`?

Comment: May I ask, if you have control over the server, why aren't you just using `mysqldump.exe`? :)

Comment: What phpMyAdmin version does that version of XAMPP include?

Answer (score 1):

Increase your URI limit in your apache server.
Your can check from
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitrequestline

Answer (score 1):

PMA's biggest drawback is that web servers weren't designed to handle bulk data like that. I've seen PMA choke on as little as 100k rows.

I would suggest mysqldump or [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) (which has the mysqldump utility built in) and work directly with MySQL instead of relying solely on PMA for bulk data movement.

Comment: I would agree with the MYSQL Workbench suggestion, its good and also Free. Although I have to say this is more of a comment than an answer!