# Uploading blob in phpMyAdmin fails with "Request-URI Too Long"

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm trying to upload a file to a mediumblob column in phpMyAdmin:

[image: error image]

When I try to upload a 100KB jpg file it works fine, but then when I try to upload a 5500KB jpg file I get an error:

> Error in Processing Request
>
> Error code: 414
>
> Error text: Request-URI Too Long

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34903030/phpmyadmin-uri-too-large

Comment: Uploading many large images in a database might not be a good use of resources. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be occurring because the max_packet_size has been exceeded.

Run the following query in the MySQL prompt

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=<Set a bigger value here>;
```

The max allowed value is **1073741824**

Comment: I got an error. it says 
Notice in .\tbl_replace.php#245.  
Undefined variable: message

Comment: @KimRusselFlores that error does not seem related to this issue. It says the variable message is not defined in tbl_replace.php . Can you share a snippet of that code so that we can look into it.

Comment: I tried to run your code and it works but when I try to insert bigger jpg(5500KB) it  says Notice in .\tbl_replace.php#245. Undefined variable: message. But I don't have the tbl_replace.php

Comment: yes it work properly, but when I try to insert the bigger size I got an error

Comment: The message you posted `Notice in .\tbl_replace.php#245. Undefined variable: message` is a Notice not an Error so this should still insert even if the image is big. Are you getting any other errors apart from this?

Comment: I have no errors aside from the Notice but still the image is not inserted to the column